# Error while executing SQL query in Eclipse

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse

I want to update a table with the code below and i used ID as Primary Key but only that error below occurs.

Thats what ive in my actionPerformed:
My PrimaryKey is "ID"

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String query="Update MitarbeiterInfo set "
                        + "Vorname='"+textField.getText()+"' ,"
                        + "Nachname='"+textField_1.getText()+"' ,"
                        + "Geburtsdatum='"+textField_2.getText()+"' ,"
                        + "Wohnadresse='"+textField_3.getText()+"' ,"
                        + "Postleitzahl='"+textField_4.getText()+"',"
                        + "Eintrittsdatum='"+textField_5.getText()+"',"
                        + "Handynummer='"+textField_6.getText()+"',"
                        + "Email='"+textField_7.getText()+"' "
                        + "ID='"+fieldID.getText()+"' "
                        + "where ID='"+fieldID.getText()+"'   ";

                PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);


                pst.execute();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mitarbeiter aktualisiert");

                pst.close();
            } catch (Exception b) {
                b.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

That Error occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "ID": syntax error)
at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:886)
at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:897)
at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:864)
at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:207)
at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:50)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:616)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:606)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:578)
at GUI$2.actionPerformed(GUI.java:139)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one last comma before updating the `ID` column (which you don't really need to do):

```
+ "Email='"+textField_7.getText()+"', "
+ "ID='"+fieldID.getText()+"' "
+ "where ID='"+fieldID.getText()+"'   ";
```

Also you don't need to use a `PreparedStatement` in this case (no parameters are being bound to the prepared query). Just use a `Statement` object:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

`+ "ID='"+fieldID.getText()+"' "`

You don't need it, when you have

`"where ID='"+fieldID.getText()+"'   ";`

It will only ever update itself to the same value.